# How to get a value of variable in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
String elkEndpoint = 'https://elastic.beta.tower.am.health.ge.com/'
```

I need to use value of `elkEndpoint` somewhere in code like below:

```
// Some code
'metrics': [
            'elasticEndpoint': elkEndpoint,
            'esConnection':    ''
        ],
// Some code
```

I tried using below, but its not working:

1. 'elasticEndpoint': elkEndpoint,
   2  'elasticEndpoint': ${elkEndpoint},
   3  'elasticEndpoint': $elkEndpoint,

What is way to use value of a variable?

Answer (score 1):

> What is way to use value of a variable?

You can do this:

```
String elkEndpoint = 'https://elastic.beta.tower.am.health.ge.com/'
Map metrics = [ elasticEndpoint: elkEndpoint, esConnection: '' ]

println metrics
```

That will output the following:

```
[elasticEndpoint:https://elastic.beta.tower.am.health.ge.com/, esConnection:]
```